# Make Content Type required in the Upload Dialog Box

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, file-upload

When I upload a file , the dialog box opens and default content type is already selected.
Is there a way that the content type is blank and the user has to choose the appropriate content type before upload.

I want to do this because when there is a pre-filled default content type users tend to not check and use the right content type.

thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You could however try adding some JS to insert an "empty" entry in DropDown...

Comment: I'm sorry but I would need quite some help on doing that because Im relativly new on SharePoint . thank you

Comment: Alternatively you could add a `ContentType` with no fields at all, and call it "Select ContentType"...

Comment: You mean create a column names "Select Content Type" and then give options on what it can be ?  Would this alternative still lead  to an organized library and files. We want to do this so we different content types that are less then 5k, allowing to view them all

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB method to achieve your requirement.

Similar issue posts for your reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/371cfd0e-074b-4806-a576-4370c6bc14f7/force-content-type-when-uploading?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/02b2f9d0-20b9-46a9-b794-fa35b0954616/how-to-have-no-default-content-type-with-multiple-content-types-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious